# CSS - Slide text background

Tags: javascript, html, css

can someone help me with some coding?
I would like to create a text slider like this one: https://gyazo.com/2dd5ad9b9022499cc4f3ac7a78c69189

It can be found on this site: https://manon.qodeinteractive.com/

I think it would be a good idea with some css, but how??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when in doubt grab the ol' marquee:
https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-marquee-tag.html

```css
marquee{
 color: transparent!important;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #b6b6b6;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #b6b6b6,1px 1px 0 #b6b6b6,-1px 1px 0 #b6b6b6,1px -1px 0 #b6b6b6;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<marquee> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  </marquee>
```

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag has never been part of any HTML specification, ever, except in the current standard which only put it there for the sole purpose of marking it as obsolete so browser vendors can warn people not to use it cause eventually it's going to be removed. So, iow, do not use `<marquee>`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css animations to change, for example, the margin:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.container {
  margin: 50px 50px auto;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  width: 200%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: -140px;
  animation: slide 10s forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% { margin-left: -140px; }
    50% { margin-left: 0; }
    100% { margin-left: -140px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    THE TEXT YOU WANT TO SHOW
  </div>
</div>
```